# View in browser shortcut for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know what is the shortcut for "View in browser" for Visual Studio 2010. I'm working currently on the project where I need to use that option a lot and it would be nice to know how to initiate this from the keyboard.

thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494417/visual-studio-view-in-browser-shortcut-to-specific-page

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> according to the [MSDN Visual Studio Tips and Tricks Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/12/08/view-in-browser-vstiptool0119.aspx).